# PyCharm Asking for GitHub Login

Tags: github, pycharm

I am cloning my Git repository using PyCharm but it is asking for Login again. When I click "Login via GitHub...", it does not login.
Then I cloned my repository using `git clone`, it worked fine. I, then, opened the directory with PyCharm and tried to Update (Pull), it is again asking for login. How to configure this problem?

Here is the Dialogue box which shows:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a token, [here are the official docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) guiding you through creating one. Its both more secure and convenient.

P.S. not enough rep to comment so I posted as an answer.

Comment: I have the same issue, but using a token does not solve it; it keeps on repeatedly asking for a login, even after successfully logging in.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to an old GitHub personal access token (PAT) saved in PyCharm remote settings. I have solved the issue by changing it into a new token.

PyCharm menu bar > Git > Manage Remotes...

In the 'Git Remotes' dialog, you can change URL for origin.

Could you give it a try in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and had it solved by changing the Remote URL from https to HTTP. As mentioned by Sukjun Kim, PyCharm menu bar > Git > Manage Remotes...